# Page not found: No CustomUser matches the given query

Tags: python, django

**Summary of project:**
(Sorry if this post is too long).
You post a funny comment and people can read your post and then click a button to like you.  If you liked their post and they liked yours then you can both chat.

**Summary of problem:**
Any time I click the "like" button on a post I get the following error:

```
    Page not found (404)
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/vote/
    Raised by:  users.views.ProfileDetailView
    - No CustomUser matches the given query.
```

So basically I cannot get the "like" button to save the current user + the post author to the "liked" table.  I've spent like two weeks reading the Django docs and trying different things in the view but now I'm just lost... I think it's my URL...

**Setting.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

**Users/models.py**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
  

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

**Userpost/models.py**

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=160, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption
```

**Voting/Models.py**

```
class Like(models.Model):
    liker = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='liker',
    )
    likee = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='likee',
    )
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Like, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**voting.views.py**

```
from .models import Like
from userposts.models import Posts

CustomUser = get_user_model()

def likePost(self, *arg, **kwargs):
    postauthor = request.GET[author_id]
    likeForm = LikeForm(request.POST)
    if likeForm.is_valid():
        likeForm = likeForm.save(commit=False)
        likeForm.liker = CustomUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        likeForm.likee = postauthor
        likeForm.save()
```

**voting/urls.py**

```
from .views import likePost


urlpatterns = [
    path('vote/', likePost, name='like_post'),
]
```

**Template**

```
{% block content %}
    {% for post in object_list %}
       <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <p>{{ post.author }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>{{ post.caption }}</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'like_post' %}">Like</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Updated: users/view.py**

```
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Profile
    slug_field = "username"
    template_name = 'account/profile.html'

    def get_object(self):
        UserName = self.kwargs.get("username")
        return get_object_or_404(CustomUser, username=UserName)
```

Comment: Likely the user did not log in.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the user did not log in, so `request.user.id` is `None`, and therefore it will not retrieve any `CustomUser`. You can use the [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) to ensure that the user has logged in. Furthermore since `CustomUser` is already the user model, you can use `request.user` directly:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def likePost(self, *arg, **kwargs):
    postauthor = request.GET[author_id]
    likeForm = LikeForm(request.POST)
    if likeForm.is_valid():
        likeForm.instance.liker = request.user
        likeForm.instance.likee = postauthor
        likeForm.save()
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: A GET request is *not* supposed to have *side-effects*, hence constructing
> objects when a user makes a GET request, is not compliant with the HTTP
> standard. Therefore it might be better to turn this into a POST request.

Comment: @Williem Van Onsem, thank you so much for taking the time to reply.  I made the updates you suggested and confirmed the user is logged in but still seem to be getting the "Page not found 404... No CustomUser matches the given query" error.  I will go through the links you provided now to see if that solves it.  I must have missed something.  Thanks again.

Comment: @SweenyJ.Finn: but the error was *No CustomUser matches the given query. *, is this still the same error at the bottom?

Comment: @SweenyJ.Finn: there is also something odd: the error says: the error is raised by the `ProfileDetailView` view, but you here share the `likePost` view? Is it possible to share the full view?

Comment: Hi Willem.  Yes, that was the same error I was getting the first time.  I have updated the post now to include the ProfileDetailView (I can add anything else that might be helpful).  It's odd because I'm not sure why it's even referencing the ProfileDetailView to be honest... I think that's why I got really lost here.

Comment: @SweenyJ.Finn: your `path('vote/', likePost, name='like_post'),` has no `username` parameter, so `self.kwargs.get('username')` will return `None`, hence the error.